# how to pass values from stdout as parameter for the next command

Tags: bash, shell, awk, grep, pipe

i want to svn blame lines of code which include "todo | fixme" 
i have the general flow of the script but struggle to combine it into one

finding the lines with "todo"

```
grep --color -Ern --include=*.{php,html,phtml} --exclude-dir=vendor "todo|TODO|FIXME" .
```

blame the line of code

```
svn blame ${file} | cat -n |grep ${linenumber}
```

i could get $file and $linenumber from the first command with awk, but i dont know how to pipe the values i extract with awk into the second command.

i am missing the glue to combine these commands into one "script" (- :

Comment: Have you tried xargs?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs

Comment: @JaimieWhiteside afaik xargs will not help because i need the linenumber value several pipes later , maybe i am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build the command with `awk` and then pipe it to `bash`:

```
grep --color -Ern --include=*.{php,html,phtml} --exclude-dir=vendor "todo|TODO|FIXME" . |\
awk -F: '{printf "svn blame \"%s\" | cat -n | grep \"%s\"\n", $1, $2}'
```

That prints one command per input line with the following format:

```
svn blame "${file}" | cat -n | grep "${linenumber}"
```

The varibales are replaces. When you execute the command as above they are only printed to the shell, that you can comfirm if everything is right. If yes add a last pipe to the in of the command that the ouput is redirected to `bash`. The complete command would look like this:

```
grep --color -Ern --include=*.{php,html,phtml} --exclude-dir=vendor "todo|TODO|FIXME" . |\
awk -F: '{printf "svn blame \"%s\" | cat -n | grep \"%s\"\n", $1, $2}' | bash
```

**A small notice**: I think you want to print the line number extracterd in the first command, aren't you? But `grep ${linenumber}` just gives the line **containing** the string `${linenumber}`. To print only the linenumber use that command: `sed -n "2p"` to print line number 2 for example. The complete command would then look like this:

```
grep --color -Ern --include=*.{php,html,phtml} --exclude-dir=vendor "todo|TODO|FIXME" . |\
awk -F: '{printf "svn blame \"%s\" | cat -n | sed -n \"%sp\"\n", $1, $2}' | bash
```